# Query on table with 100,000 records

Tags: mysql

I have a large table on the MySQL database where it has more than 100,000 records

the problem I have a column called "profile_picture" containing the binary date of the image saved on this column.

So, the select query on this table is very very slow. How I can optimize that?

Comment: Please post TEXT of the A) QUERY and the results of B) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS tbl_name;  for each table involved and D) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query).

Comment: What is a "binary date"?  "00110100111010001110101"?

Answer (score 0):

> ... large table ... more than 100,000 records

That's not "large" - not even *close* to "large".
Stick a handful of zeroes on the end of that and you're getting up to "large".

> the problem ... column called "profile_picture" containing the binary data of the image ...

In itself, that column *should not* be an issue.

> So, the select query on this table is very very slow. How I can optimize that?

By *tuning* the query.

Now, there are a *lot* of *really good* people around here but, as far as I know, *none* of them are psychic.
Show us the errant query and the structure of the table(s) that it uses.

*Most likely*, you're query is filtering rows by a column that doesn't have an index on it but, until we see the actual query, we can't be sure.